Visual Studio Hot Reload reloads for every changes
I am using VS2022 Community and developing ASP.NET applications. I am using hot reload when checking some style changes and works fine my other project. But my one another project hot reload is reloading every changes like changing class name on html elements or changing content of label element. Do you know why?
